# MEAN.io create CRUD application

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean

I have practiced with MEAN stack (angular 2), I already created an application with CRUD for 2 table, and now I wanna take data from table 2 for table 1 as a constraint field, like book with it's category. How do you guys do it? please teach me. 
Sorry for my bad English, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a component to show the book details which I think you already have created.

Now, you have to create another component that will get the category Id from the book details component. You can use one way databind for this.

Take a look at this Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3